# total of values record from the sql database

Tags: c#, sql

I want to return the total of the values in record "hours" on the table "Courses" from my sql database I tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Courses.hours from Courses inner join Sched on Courses.Id = Sched.SCourses ", con2);
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read())
{
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select sum(hours) as totalHours from Courses");
    Label3.Text = cmd2.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specified the connection for your sql command cmd2 .
Try this .

```
 SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select sum(hours) as totalHours from Courses",con2);
 Label3.Text = cmd2.ExexcuteScalar().ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in the code: doing `while (rdr.Read())` you loop through all rows of result set and execute `Select sum(hours)...` as many times as many rows you get in the first query.

Depends on requirements, you might want to do `if` instead of `while`

```
if (rdr.Read())
```

Next, `cmd2.ToString();` will not output the result of the query. You should either use `ExecuteReader` as in the first case, or use ExecuteScalar

```
if (rdr.Read())
{
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select sum(hours) as totalHours from Courses", con2);
    Label3.Text = cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();  
}
```

Comment: So `cmd2.ToString();` will execute the query and assign result to `Label3.Text`  if you place `if (rdr.Read())` instead for while, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you totaling your hours using separate queries. Use `group by` clause and run only once.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Courses.id, Sum(Courses.hours) from Courses inner join Sched on Courses.Id = Sched.SCourses group by Course.id")
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
Label3.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Hope it will help.